Missing header files for linux development
I am new to linux development and I want to develop a linux module, but I am running into an issue.
Some header files, notably <linux/init.h>, are missing (/not found)
I am currently using Visual Studio 2022 on my Windows desktop and am building my project through SSH on my Raspberry Pi 5.
I successfully connected my Raspberry Pi 5 to Visual Studio and see that most header files are being synced (ie: kernel.h and module.h).
Also double checked at C:\Users\op\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0.
That being said, as mentioned above, I am missing init.h
After looking at other prior posts from different people, I have double checked that linux-headers-generic is installed, which it is:
op@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-arm64' instead of 'linux-headers-generic'
linux-headers-arm64 is already the newest version (6.1.90-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

and
op@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712 is already the newest version (1:6.6.28-1+rpt1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

So I am kind of lost at this point, any help is appreciated.
EDIT:
When running find, the init.h header is found...
op@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo find /usr -name init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.28+rpt-common-rpi/include/trace/stages/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.28+rpt-common-rpi/include/linux/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.28+rpt-common-rpi/include/linux/sched/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-rpi4-common-rpi/include/trace/stages/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-rpi4-common-rpi/include/linux/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-rpi4-common-rpi/include/linux/sched/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-21-common/include/trace/stages/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-21-common/include/linux/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-21-common/include/linux/sched/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-21-common/arch/x86/include/asm/init.h

Which does correspond to my kernel version:
op@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -r 
6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712


In what sense exactly are they "missing (/not found)"? If you are trying to make Intellisense aware of kernel headers, there's some information here: An IntelliSense Bug When Coding Linux Kernel Module

@steeldriver What I meant is that intellisense is not aware of it, nor does it compile when I try to. The solution you linked is in regards to Visual Studio Code, whereas I am using Visual Studio. I suppose I could try it out, however I would of preferred staying with Visual Studio...
